# I am receiving an error while trying to use chromedriver.exe on python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am receiving this error:

```
File "bot.py", line 10, in self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe') NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

The code I am using is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')


self.driver.get('wwww.instagram.com')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ig_bot = InstagramBot('temp_username', 'temp_password')
    print(ig_bot.username)
```

Chrome is opening for about 2 seconds and then it is closing by itself, I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check your indentation, are those supposed to be in `__init__`?

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is incorrect.

```
class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get('wwww.instagram.com')
```